# : colon command for bash

Tags: bash

Speaking as a bash newbie I have been upgrading my .bashrc via copy/paste + github and I have come across the `:` command that stumps both me and google. e.g. `: ${USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR:=~/.bash_completion.d}`.

Without this statement originally in my .bashrc, and typing this stuff into my terminal (**->** indicates relevant output):

```
: ${USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR=~/.bash_completion.d}
echo $USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR
-> /Users/sh/.bash_completion.d
```

And:

```
: ${USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR=~/.bash_completion.d}
export USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR=asdf
echo $USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR
-> asdf
```

But:

```
: ${USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR=~/.bash_completion.d}
export USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR=asdf
: ${USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR=~/.bash_completion.d}
echo $USER_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR
-> asdf
```

I don't get it!

1) How does the colon command set a variable but cannot overwrite one set by `export`?

2) What is the logic behind using `:` in some .bashrc?

Using Mac 10.6.8

(out of context include of keyword colon just to help others like me who tried to search for that term)

Comment: See the excellent answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390406/usage-of-colon-dash-in-bash

Comment: You can read about it here. https://www.aplawrence.com/Basics/leading-colon.html#:~:text=Bash%20and%20sh%20both%20use,(%22while%20%3A%22).&text=So%20that's%20why%20those%20leading%20colons%20are%20often%20found%20in%20shell%20scripts.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`:` is a shell builtin that is basically equivalent to the `true` command. It is often used as a no-op eg after an `if` statement. You can read more about it in [this question from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin).

The `${varname=value}` basically means set the value of `$varname` to `value` if `$varname` is not already set, and then return the value of $varname. Though if you try to run that at the command line it will try to run the value returned. Putting the `:` in front as a no-op prevents bash from trying to run the value.

Note there are two slightly different forms:

```
${varname:=value}
```

sets varname to value if varname is either unset or null.

```
${varname=value}
```

only sets the value of varname if varname is currently unset (i.e., it will not change varname from "" to value)

(Thank you to chepner for clarifying that in a comment).

[Someone else referencing this method](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-setting-default-values-for-shell-variables.html)